# Understanding this shell scripting assignment

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu

I need some help understanding this Linux programming assignment.
I have to use this C program that will randomize a text file and here is the program:

```
//
// shuffle.c
// Filter that reads every line from stdin (or a specified file), 
// shuffles them randomly, and outputs the shuffled lines to stdout.
// This is a partial replacement for the 'shuf' command provided
// with most Linux installations.
// Author: W. Cochran wcochran@wsu.edu
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//
// Seed stdlib's random() with a random
// seed using kernel urandom device.
//
void seedRandom(void) {
  FILE *f;
  if ((f = fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb")) == NULL) {
    perror("/dev/urandom");
    exit(-1);
  }
  unsigned int seed;
  fread(&seed, sizeof(seed), 1, f);
  fclose(f);
  srandom(seed);
}

//
// Fisher–Yates shuffle using stdlib's random()
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#Potential_sources_of_bias
// Not really doing this exactly right, see
// https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful
// 
void shuffle(int numLines, char *lines[]) {  
  for (int i = 0; i < numLines-1; i++) {
    const int n = numLines - i;
    const int j = random() % n + i;
    char *tmp = lines[i];
    lines[i] = lines[j];
    lines[j] = tmp;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  //
  // Read from stdin by default else read from
  // first argument specified on command line.
  //
  FILE *f = stdin;
  if (argc >= 2) {
    f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (f == NULL) {
      perror(argv[1]);
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  //
  // Buffer each input line into (dynamically sized) array.
  // Caveat: Assume lines are less than 200 chars long (I'm too
  // lazy to do this right).
  //
  int capacity = 10;
  int numLines = 0;
  char **lines = (char **) malloc(capacity * sizeof(char *));
  char buf[200];
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f) != NULL) {
    if (numLines >= capacity) {
      capacity *= 2;
      lines = realloc(lines, capacity * sizeof(char *));
    }
    lines[numLines++] = strdup(buf);
  }

  fclose(f);

  //
  // Seed random number generator used by shuffle.
  //
  seedRandom();

  //
  // Shuffle lines.
  //
  shuffle(numLines, lines);

  //
  // Echo shuffled lines to stdout.
  //
  for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    printf("%s", lines[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

The assignment tells me the following:

[image: so I can't copy and paste because the pdf is troublesome but I have included a screenshot I hope you can find it.]

I just need help on getting through this point, please.

How do I use `shuffle` once I compile it? What's the point of using the code that was just provided in the screenshot that I provided?

Comment: It is telling you that you need to use the `shuffle` command.  It could be installed on your system, or not.  If it is, you can use it.  If it is not installed, the teacher gave you the code for it, which you can compile and use.  The "script" looks if it is installed, if not it assumes it will be found in the current directory.  FYI in English, `i` alone is always capitalized, so `I`.

Comment: The code is sloppy; if you type `shuffle file1 file2 file3`, it will shuffle the lines of text in   `file1` and completely ignore `file2` and `file3`.  So, correct use of the program is `shuffle file` — it will write the lines of the file in a shuffled order.

Comment: Note that there's a bug in the quoted shell script.  It reads `1>& 2`; the space is incorrect and the redirection should be `1>&2` (or even just `>&2`).

Comment: It would be preferable if you transcribed the instructions from your PDF into the question, rather than embedding an image of text.  All else apart, the image is unreadable on a mobile device.

Comment: @yesitsme : Also, as you can see from the C-code, you can run `shuffle` without arguments, in which case it processes stdin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That block of script code sets the variable `SHUF` to the program you should use to shuffle a file. Either it will be the system's `shuf` program or your teacher's `shuffle` program.

After the code is done, you can use `$SHUF` to run whichever program was found.

```
$SHUF filename.txt
```